# Using the inclusion-exclusion principle to calculate the proportion of numbers divisible by factors

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $m_1, ..., m_r$ be pairwise coprime numbers and $N=\prod\limits_{i=1}^r m_i$ . 
So I'm trying to calculate the proportion of the numbers 1 to N that are not divisible by any of the $m_i$, so I've used the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,  but I have a really long expression of sums and was wondering how I can simplify it?

So for the size of the set of all numbers between 1 and n not divisible by any of the $m_i$ is :
$$N-\sum_{i} N/m_i + \sum_{i<j} N/m_im_j - \sum_{i<j<k} N/m_im_jm_k \quad + ...$$
Then for the proportion just dividing through by N I got:
$$1-\sum_{i} 1/m_i + \sum_{i<j} 1/m_im_j - \sum_{i<j<k} 1/m_im_jm_k \quad + ...$$

Comment: What's that expression? What did you try?

Comment: I've edited the question to answer this, I just figured out how to write summations.

Comment: I'd say the expression is correct. It cannot really be simplified.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly I would suggest not dividing through by N, at least not initially.
Imagine you have $r=3$, then
$$
N-\sum_i \frac{N}{m_i} + ... = m_1m_2m_3 + m_1m_2 + m_1m_3 + m_2m_3 - m_1 - m_2 - m_3 - 1 
$$
Then, clearly
$$
m_1m_2m_3 + m_1m_2 + m_1m_3 + m_2m_3 - m_1 - m_2 - m_3 - 1 = (m_1-1)(m_2-1)(m_3-1)
$$
This can be expanded to larger values of r.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful :)